# What does "there exists a subset $S_0 \subset S$ of full $\mu$-measure" mean?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am reading a paper and there is a theorem which says:

Let $(S, A, \mu)$ be a probability space, and let $\theta$ be a $\mu$-measure
preserving transformation on it. Then
there exists a subset $S_0 \subset S$ of full $\mu$-measure such that ....

What does "there exists a subset $S_0 \subset S$ of full $\mu$-measure" mean?

Answer (score 3):

In general, this would mean that there is some $S_0$ contained in $S$ with $\mu(S \setminus S_0)=0$ (which has some additional property). In the context of a probability space this can be rewritten as $\mu(S_0)=1$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

That's mean there is a mesurable subset $S_0 \subset S$ with $\mu(S_0) = 1$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.